# Bitwise Remainder Operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I've been messing around with bitwise operator problems I've found on the internet and have found one that just completely stumps me.

```
int rpwr2(int x, int n)
{
   //Legal ops: ! ~ ^ | + << >>

   //My attempt at a solution:
   int power = (1 << n) + ~0;
   return x & power;
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: The program that checks the answer is saying that it is incorrect:

"Test rempwr2(-2147483647[0x80000001], 1[0x1]) failed...
... Gives 1[0x1]. Should be -1[0xffffffff]"

Comment: Does it have to be portable, or can we assume two's complement and arithmetic right shift?

Comment: Conditionally negate the result with `int mask = x >> 31; return (result + mask) ^ mask;` Not portable, obviously.

Comment: These problems are solely built for an Intel 32bit architecture.
We can assume two's complement and arithmetic right shift.

Comment: @harold, I tried your suggestion of "return ((x & power) + mask) ^ mask" but it checks to be "Gives -1. Should be 0."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255734/bitwise-remainder-operator#comment23259499_16255734) is almost correct, but instead of `-result`, for negative `x`, we need

```
result - (1 << n)
```

unless result is 0. In two's complement,

```
x & ((1 << n) - 1)
```

is congruent to `x` modulo `2^n` for every `x` (and `n` small enough for `1 << n` to work correctly). That is the representant of `x`'s residue class in the interval `[0, 2^n)`.

The requirement is to get a negative (non-positive, more precisely) remainder (in the interval `(-2^n, 0]`) for negative `x`. That means, for negative `x` that are not multiples of `2^n`, we must subtract `2^n` from `x & ((1 << n) - 1)`.

```
int rempwr2(int x, int n)
{
   //Compute x%(2^n) for 0 <= n <= 30.
   //Negative arguments should yield a negative remainder.
   //Examples: rempwr2(15, 2) = 3; rempwr2(-35, 3) = -3;
   //Legal ops: ! ~ ^ | + << >>

   //My attempt at a solution:
   int power = (1 << n) + ~0;  // 2^n - 1
   int mask = x >> 31;
   int result = x & power;
   return (x & power) + (((~((!!result) << n)) + 1) & mask);
}
```

If `x >= 0`, then `mask = 0`, and `(x & power) + (whatever & mask) = (x & power)` is the correct result.

For `x < 0`, we must subtract `1 << n`, unless `result = 0`.

```
(!!result) << n
```

is 0 if `x` is a multiple of `2^n`, and `2^n` otherwise. Since direct subtraction is not permitted, we must negate that (`-n = ~n + 1` in two's complement), so we find

```
(~((!!result) << n)) + 1
```

is still 0 if `result = 0`, and `-2^n` otherwise, hence that is what we must add for negative `x`. But that can also be a non-zero value for positive `x`, hence we must nullify it in that case, which we do by taking the bitwise and with `mask` (which is 0 for `x >= 0` and has all bits set for `x < 0`).

Comment: This seems like we're on the right track, but is still incorrect:
When checking, rempwr2(-2147483647, 2), it gave -1 when it should have given -3.

Comment: @PDutt Got it now, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @harold Yes, you're right. I was irritated by the wrong result, however we don't need `-(x & power)` for negative `x`, but `(x & power) - (1 << n)`, unless the remainder is 0.

Comment: It worked! Could you explain the return statement in a little more detail? What was your thought process for coming up with this solution?

Comment: @PDutt I've expanded the explanation a bit. Does that make it clear?